# How to change content type in django restframework api from json to multipart/form-data or form data

Tags: django, image, api, content-type

[image]

How to change the content type in Django REST framework API and how to change the set content type in serializer and viewset for multipart/form-data or form data?

```
from rest_framework import serializers,routers
from .models import *
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

-----------------------Serializer----------------------

class filedataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=filedata
        fields='__all__'

-----------------------Viewset--------------------------

class filedataViewsets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    queryset=filedata.objects.all()`enter code here`
    serializer_class=filedataSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

#### AJAX

> If you don't set the content type, most clients will default to using
> `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`, which may not be what you wanted.
>
> As an example, if you are sending json encoded data using jQuery with
> the `.ajax()` method, you should make sure to include the `contentType: 'application/json'` setting

#### Browsable API

When you submit your data through the tab **`Raw data`** , the `Content-Type` is set as `application/json`.

While if you submit your data through the the tab **`HTML form`**, the `Content-Type` is set as `text/html; charset=utf-8`.

And if you specify `parser_classes = MultipartParser` in your `Viewset`, `DRF` will automatically set the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` as showed below, so you don't need to bother with the header settings in the frontend.

```
class MultiPartParser(BaseParser):
    """
    Parser for multipart form data, which may include file data.
    """
    media_type = 'multipart/form-data'

    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
        ...
        encoding = parser_context.get('encoding', settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET)
        meta = request.META.copy()
        meta['CONTENT_TYPE'] = media_type
        ...
```